# using iMessage as a server?

Tags: ios, imessage

Is it possible to use iMessage as a webservice? and have it communicate with an app? 
Most online info talks about sms and how an app can send an sms message, but not use it or consume it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wont be able to get any documented API to send and receive data via iMessage in your application.